# Funtion generator does not throw an error that is catched by another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

So I was playing with Redux-Saga when came to a error handling stuff.
The problem is that the function generator has try catch block and it calls `getAllUserColivings` function. This function catches the error `Request failed with status code 404`. I did that on purpose (messed up url). However, the generator does not catched any errors and done success function which is not great.

Here is the generator code (yes, I know that JWT token should not be in localStorage, but it is for now)

```
  try {
    const jwtToken = yield localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    const colivings = yield getAllUserColivings(jwtToken);
    yield console.log(colivings, "coliving");
    yield put(updateColivingsSuccess(colivings));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(updateColivingsFailure(error));
  }
}
```

Here is the `getAllUserColivings` function code:

````
  try {
    const validation = await getUserIDByJWT(jwt);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("strapi_id", validation);
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8000/includes/settings/colivins.php",
      formData,
      headers
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return console.log(error.message);
  }
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning the whole error, not console.log function.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same. However, it still puts success function. Sends payload: error

Comment: Somehow it works. However, partially because it puts success function and then failure function